# Getting Salesforce user Information Using Identity Service

Tags: jquery, salesforce-id, ajax

Using OAuth2 and REST with a custom created Remote APP, I am not able to get user Information using sales Force.com Identity Service by using jqury ajax call, however when i use postman of chrome to test the service i successfully get the information of the user, but when i use jquery ajax call i always get 404 error message , am i missing something....?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D28.....",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer 00D28000000KcLw!AQoAQA_IKxeZAxuswh0......",
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log('the result ' + JSON.stringify(response));

    }).error(function (error) {
        console.log('the error mesasge is ' + error);
    });
```

Using OAuth2 and REST with a custom created Remote APP, I am not able to get user Information using sales Force.com Identity Service by using jqury ajax call, however when i use postman of chrome to test the service i successfully get the information of the user, but when i use jquery ajax call i always get 404 error message , am i missing something....?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D28.....",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer 00D28000000KcLw!AQoAQA_IKxeZAxuswh0......",
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log('the result ' + JSON.stringify(response));

    }).error(function (error) {
        console.log('the error mesasge is ' + error);
    });
```

Thanks in advance